# Keras - Image Classification with two classes Tensorflow Python

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

i want to classify two classes with CNN.

- **first class** are objects(car, building, and so go an)
- **secound class** are NoObjects(for example Background without objects)

So, the question is, how can I realize this? I want to have many objects images for the CNN. I saw a example with Cat and Dog.. But I have only images for one class. The other class are the background. It is possible to create a background class??

I´m very new in CNN..

Comment: I can't understand properly but it may solves your problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225701/what-exactly-is-a-background-class-in-a-classification-problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're talking about [semantic segmentation](https://medium.com/nanonets/how-to-do-image-segmentation-using-deep-learning-c673cc5862ef), where you have a variable N number of classes to localize (in this case N=1) plus the background class. There's a lot of literature and baseline models out there that can help you out. I recommend these two since they're the most popular ones:

- Pretrained models: [Tensorflow's model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)
- Datasets: Specifically [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#home)